# Open specific tab on a form from event handler on another form

Tags: c#

I've got the following form that has a menu strip and what I want to do say is if the user clicks "Deposit Funds" on this picture

[image: Main Form]

and then on another form the "Deposit" tab opens automatically

[image: Tabbed Form]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a public method on the so called "other form":

```
public void SelectDepositFundsTab() {
    tabControl.SelectedTab = tabDepositFunds;
}
```

And call this method in the event handler of the toolStripMenuItem:

```
private void toolStripMenuItemDepositFunds_Clicked() {
    // Optional, depending if your otherForm is already existing
    var otherForm = new OtherForm();
    otherForm.Show();
    // Select the tab
    otherForm.SelectDepositFundsTab();
}
```

Comment: Does that go into the Event Handler?

Comment: I assume the tabControl is private, so you will have to create a public method on the "other form" and include this line of code. See my edit.

Comment: Almost there, I'm getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Opens a blank form, not the tabbed form I wanted. It's like its after creating a form